# the function isAssignableFrom does not work properly in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem that I cannot understand. First of all, I want to denote my structure:

I have a class named *ClassMetadata*. It is metadata about class values:

```
public class ClassMetadata<T extends Object> {

    private int serviceId;

    private int typeId;

    private int revisionId;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private Class clazz;
  
    private ClassAttribute[] classAttributeArray; 

    private ClassMetadata() {
    
    }

    public ClassMetadata(int serviceId, Class<T> clazz) {

        this();

        this.serviceId = serviceId;
        this.clazz = clazz;

    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Class<T> getClazz() {
        return clazz;     
    }
    
    
     // getters and setters 
}
```

*Argument* is a class that responsible from conveying class argument to a function:

```
public class Argument<T> {

    private ClassMetadata<T> classMetadata;

    private T sample;

    public Argument(ClassMetadata<T> classMetadata, T sample) {
        super();
        this.classMetadata = classMetadata;
        this.sample = sample;
    }

    // getters and setters
    
    
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public boolean isAssignableFrom (Class classInstance) {

        if (classInstance == null || this.classMetadata == null)
            return false;
         
        Class localClassValue = this.classMetadata.getClazz();

        if (localClassValue == null)
            return false;

        return localClassValue.isAssignableFrom(classInstance);
        
    }
}
```

I have an *IRepositoryEntityFramework* interface that manages database interactions of a project:

```
package authority.core.dataaccess.entityframework;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;

public interface IRepositoryEntityFramework<T> extends AutoCloseable {

    void add(T value) throws PersistenceException;
    
    void update(T value) throws PersistenceException;
    
    void delete(T value) throws PersistenceException;
    
    //commit
    void save() throws PersistenceException ;    
    
    List<T> readList(SQL sqlClause) throws IllegalStateException, PersistenceException;
    
}
```

I have a *IAuthorityDetailRepository* that responsible specifically *AuthorityDetail* entity's database operations:

```
package authority.repository.conceptual;

import authority.core.dataaccess.entityframework.IRepositoryEntityFramework;
import authority.entities.concrete.AuthorityDetail;

public interface IAuthorityDetailRepository extends IRepositoryEntityFramework<AuthorityDetail> {

}
```

When I call the clauses below, *isAssignableFrom* returns false:

```
IAuthorityDetailRepository authorityDetailRepository = DependencyResolver.getSample().resolve(IAuthorityDetailRepository.class);
    
ClassMetadata<IAuthorityDetailRepository> authorityDetailRepositoryMetadata = new ClassMetadata(3,IAuthorityDetailRepository.class );
            
Argument<IAuthorityDetailRepository> authorityDetailRepositoryArgument = new Argument<IAuthorityDetailRepository>(authorityDetailRepositoryMetadata, authorityDetailRepository);
            
        authorityDetailRepositoryArgument.isAssignableFrom(IRepositoryEntityFramework.class);
```

However, the clauses below return true;

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Class localClassValue = IAuthorityDetailRepository.class;
            
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
Class argumentClassValue = IRepositoryEntityFramework.class;            
            
localClassValue.isAssignableFrom( argumentClassValue);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

**Update-1**

As Mr. Sergey Kalinichenko pointed out that *Argument* was missing, which implements the failing *isAssignableFrom* method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `java.lang.Class#isAssignableFrom` JavaDoc says:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter. It returns true if so; otherwise it returns false.

So, it returns `true` when called next way:

```
Base.class.isAssignableFrom(Child.class); // true
```

In your case, you're calling

```
IAuthorityDetailRepository.class.isAssignableFrom(IRepositoryEntityFramework.class)
```

Since `IAuthorityDetailRepository` is a child of `IRepositoryEntityFramework`, method returns `false`. If you intended different behaviour, just swap `localClassValue` and `classInstance`.

```
return classInstance.isAssignableFrom(localClassValue);
```